# Does any SQL frontend display sub-datasheets?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, frontend

I'm looking for an SQL client app that can display [subdatasheets](https://web.archive.org/web/20131116192534/http://www.vb123.com:80/toolshed/00_Docs/subdatasheetsplus.htm) like the following:

[image]
<sub>(source: [vb123.com](http://www.vb123.com/toolshed/00_docs/sdfigure1.gif))</sub>

Do you know of any?

Comment: You could also try openoffice.org database client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Maestro products do include this functionality:

http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/mysql/maestro/screenshots/getting_started/data_grid/

Comment: Do the sub datasheets popup in a new window overlapping the rows below? Or do they push down the rows below?

Comment: They push down the rows below (like MS Access does).

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft access can do it for mySQL

[Here is more information on the topic](http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/204346-subdatasheets-how-use-subform)

It indicates that you can open a Table or a Query then in the insert menu select subdatasheet. Then you use the child and link Master fields to get the display you are looking for.

You could also try the database client in openoffice.org

Comment: I added a link that has more information to this topic. Sadly I have not found any.

Comment: Access cannot (as of Office 2013) use subdatasheets on linked tables (using an ODBC connection to SQL)